# Order of execution of 2 Process Builders

Tags: process-builder, order-of-execution

I am now merging our too many process builders and WFR's into as minimum as needed PB's.
I am doing this mainly to control the OOE on the objects.

I now have 2 PB's on Task object, one is on Create only, and the other is on Create and Every Edit.

Is there an order for the execution between them? I would assume that the 'Create Only' will fire first, but is it?

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot guarantee the order of Processes. You can generally assume that on any given day, they will *probably* execute in the same order, but across releases, patches, restarts, and deployments, they may change order arbitrarily. In fact, the way the system is designed, you should pretend that all the processes execute simultaneously, as they cannot see changes made by other processes in the same execution cycle (you can use the "reevaluate on update" advanced option, but processes will only see the changes on the next cycle).

Comment: Thanks, If I use the 'Evaluate Next Criteria' on the PB step - will the next step see the 'Updated' Data, or 'Original' data?

Comment: @Saariko [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_next_criteria.htm&type=5): *IMPORTANT When a process continues to the next criteria node, it evaluates the values that the record had at the beginning of the process.* So, no, even further criteria won't see updated values until the next cycle.

Comment: @sfdcfox - My next criteria node does see updated values- see [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/292407/scheduled-action-not-firing-in-process-builder-on-create). Until this [critical update](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_cruc_criteria.htm) is applied, you might see the opposite behavior. However, you should assume you can't do it and not rely on it if it does work if you test

Comment: @KrisGoncalves Oh. Didn't know it was broken. Thanks for the info.